# Login script not reading password properly?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm trying to make a log-in script but it doesn't seem to be reading the password correctly from my database and I don't know why.

This is my php code:

```
<? 

if ($_POST['login'] == "login") {
  include('db.php');
  include('inc/scriptsandstyles.php'); 
  include('inc/passwordLib.php');

    $username = (isset($_POST['username'])? $_POST['username'] : null);
    $password = (isset($_POST['password'])? $_POST['password'] : null);

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_name, user_password FROM rgitportal_users WHERE user_name='$username'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    $pw_hash = $row['user_password'];

if (password_verify($password, $pw_hash)) {

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://rgitportal.com/home.html"</script>';

} else {
    $errormsg = "Username or password incorrect";
}

}
?>
```

This is how the password_verify function is declared (Running php version 5.3) and is inside the passwordLib.php which is included in log on script.

```
if (!function_exists('password_verify')){
function password_verify($password, $hash){
    return (crypt($password, $hash) === $hash);
  }
}
```

This is the form code:

```
<form id="login_form"  name ="login" id ="login" action ="index.php" method = "POST">
    <div class ="field_container">
         Username: <input type="text" name ="username" id ="username"></input>
            </div>
    <div class ="field_container">
         Password: <input type="password" name ="password" id ="password"></input>
            </div>
    <div class ="field_container">
        <input type="submit" value="login" name ="login" id="login"></input>
            </div>
     <span style="color:#FF0000;"><?=$errormsg?></span>
 </form>
```

If I enter the username and password correctly it always falls into the else of my if statement which checks the password. The variables are getting assigned properly from both the form and the database in question. The text field in the database which holds the password is stored as a password so therefore is encrypted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'The text field in the database which holds the password is stored as a password so therefore is encrypted'. Are you using a `PASSWORD` function of database?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be of help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

The First example is showing, that you should use hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($user_password[, $optional_salt])) for verifying.

(For older PHP Versions, taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php):

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('hash_equals')) {
  function hash_equals($str1, $str2) {
    if(strlen($str1) != strlen($str2)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      $res = $str1 ^ $str2;
      $ret = 0;
      for($i = strlen($res) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) $ret |= ord($res[$i]);
      return !$ret;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Keep in mind, that crypt is using a salt as second parameter and not the hashed password.

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the second parameter of crypt() should not be $hash. What salt did you use when you create and store the password in the database?

Answer (score -1):

Try making below changes in your code :

**Main code**

```
if (password_verify($password, $pw_hash)) 
{
     header('Location:http://rgitportal.com/home.html');
} else 
{
    $errormsg = "Username or password incorrect";
}
```

**passwordLib.php**

```
if (!function_exists('password_verify'))
{
   function password_verify($password, $hash)
   {
       return (crypt($password) === $hash);
   }
}
```